# Natulius "Connect to server"

Tags: server, ssh, connection, ftp

i used to manage the remote servers connection with the bookmarks options. Since 14.04 the connections i used is saved in a popup window - how do i edit them?

also - if there is a better way of connection to remote servers please tell me. i tried using eclipse remote system explorer and other software from the Software center and it's not quite right... i miss WINscp :( (it's the only thing i miss from windows, though),

also , i prefer not to use wine.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternative programs, similar to WinSCP (probably) - for example [gFTP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gftp/)
[image: screenshot]

and [FileZilla](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/filezilla/):
[image: screenshot]

You can install both by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gftp filezilla
```

The GUI for Nautilus's servers does not have many options, but you should be able to edit the entries by running:

```
gedit ~/.config/nautilus/servers
```